# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'barcodeScanner' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:29

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to utilize the PhoneGap Plugin for Scanning the Barcode and got stuck in the middle.

The problem looks to be with window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan in index.html. Don't know how to fix it.

---

### index.html:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function scanCode(){
                window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
                function(result){
                    alert("Scanned Code: " + result.text 
                    + ". Format: " + result.format
                    + ". Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
                }, 
                function(error){
                    alert("Scan failed: " + error);
                }
            );
        }

        function encodeData(){
            var data = document.getElementById("data").value;
            if (data != ''){
                    window.plugins.barcodeScanner.encode(
                    BarcodeScanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE, data, 
                    function(success){
                        alert("Encode success: " + success);
                    }, 
                    function(fail){
                        alert("Encoding failed: " + fail);
                    }
                );
            }
            else{
                alert("Please enter some data.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Barcode/QR Code Scanner And Encoder</h3>

    <input type="button" value="Scan Code" onclick="scanCode();"/><br/><br/>

    Data : <br/>
    <input type="text" name="data" id="data" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Encode Data" onclick="encodeData();"/>
</body>
```

---

barcodescanner.js:

---

/**
 * cordova is available under *either* the terms of the modified BSD license *or* the
 * MIT License (2008). See http://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical for full text.
 *
 * Copyright (c) Matt Kane 2010
 * Copyright (c) 2011, IBM Corporation
 */

```
    var exec = require("cordova/exec");

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @returns {BarcodeScanner}
     */
    function BarcodeScanner() {

        /**
         * Encoding constants.
         *
         * @type Object
         */
        this.Encode = {
            TEXT_TYPE: "TEXT_TYPE",
            EMAIL_TYPE: "EMAIL_TYPE",
            PHONE_TYPE: "PHONE_TYPE",
            SMS_TYPE: "SMS_TYPE"
            //  CONTACT_TYPE: "CONTACT_TYPE",  // TODO:  not implemented, requires passing a Bundle class from Javascript to Java
            //  LOCATION_TYPE: "LOCATION_TYPE" // TODO:  not implemented, requires passing a Bundle class from Javascript to Java
        };
    };

    /**
     * Read code from scanner.
     *
     * @param {Function} successCallback This function will recieve a result object: {
     *        text : '12345-mock',    // The code that was scanned.
     *        format : 'FORMAT_NAME', // Code format.
     *        cancelled : true/false, // Was canceled.
     *    }
     * @param {Function} errorCallback
     */
    BarcodeScanner.prototype.scan = function (successCallback, errorCallback) {
        if (errorCallback == null) {
            errorCallback = function () {
            };
        }

        if (typeof errorCallback != "function") {
            console.log("BarcodeScanner.scan failure: failure parameter not a function");
            return;
        }

        if (typeof successCallback != "function") {
            console.log("BarcodeScanner.scan failure: success callback parameter must be a function");
            return;
        }

        exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'BarcodeScanner', 'scan', []);
    };

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    BarcodeScanner.prototype.encode = function (type, data, successCallback, errorCallback, options) {
        if (errorCallback == null) {
            errorCallback = function () {
            };
        }

        if (typeof errorCallback != "function") {
            console.log("BarcodeScanner.encode failure: failure parameter not a function");
            return;
        }

        if (typeof successCallback != "function") {
            console.log("BarcodeScanner.encode failure: success callback parameter must be a function");
            return;
        }

        exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'BarcodeScanner', 'encode', [
            {"type": type, "data": data, "options": options}
        ]);
    };

    var barcodeScanner = new BarcodeScanner();
    module.exports = barcodeScanner;
```

Comment: It looks like the barcode scanner is more up to date than your 2.2 version. You are trying to call `window.plugins.barcodescanner` but I don't think you ever assign the barcode scanner to that `window.plugins` namespace. What happens in the console if you type `window.plugins`? Look at the code at the bottom of the old version and try this: https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner/commit/92197289049bfd4aab63b6467dddb93449a8a7ef#diff-46e6e4bd318e5aec83e6d40fbd3ccd59  Or, just update your cordova version to 3.x instead of 2.2.0

Comment: MBillau, Upgrading the PhoneGap resolved the issue. Thx.